# Any consideration moving an ASP.NET application from Intel machine to AMD?

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008, intel, amd-processor

I have a working ASP.NET application which uses memory extensively and recently I have planned to move to an AMD machine. Is there anything I should take care of (i.e libraries I use in my `Bin` folder, SQL Server 2008, etc...)

Comment: staying at the same bit 32 or 64?

Answer (score 1):

IA32 (x86) is IA32 (x86) and AMD64 (x86-64) is AMD64 (x86-64) -- this is ignoring the usage of additional/extension instructions, but x86 hardware is *very* backwards-compatible.

"Machine independent" libraries (e.g. most .NET Assemblies) are perfectly fine (as long as they run from a compatible run-time) and "machine dependent" libraries should be okay if they are run in the same "bitness" environment (which is not necessarily the same as the machine "bitness").

As with any migration, plan extra slack in downtime, and establish/test the new environment before removing the old -- and remember to have fun!